# Path building python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am building a class to download files asynchronously.However i am facing a weird bug.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from requests_futures.sessions import FuturesSession
import os
import pathlib


class AsyncDownloader:
    """Download files asynchronously"""

    __urls = set()
    __dest_path = None
    __user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:58.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/58.0'
    __read_timeout = 60
    __connection_timeout = 30

    def setSourceCSV(self, source_path, column_name):
        self.source_path = source_path
        self.column_name = column_name

        try:
            my_csv = pd.read_csv(source_path, usecols=[self.column_name], chunksize=10)
        except ValueError:
            print("The column name doesn't exist")
            return
        else:
            # No exception whatsoever
            for chunk in my_csv:
                AsyncDownloader.__urls.update(set(getattr(chunk, self.column_name)))

    def setDestinationPath(self, dest_path):
        if dest_path.endswith('/'):
            dest_path = dest_path[:-1]
        self.dest_path = dest_path
        # Make directory if not exist
        # TODO Add exception in case we can't create the directory
        pathlib.Path(self.dest_path).mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
        if os.access(self.dest_path, os.W_OK):
            AsyncDownloader.__dest_path = pathlib.Path(self.dest_path).resolve()

    def setUserAgent(self, useragent):
        self.useragent = useragent
        AsyncDownloader.__user_agent = self.useragent

    def setConnectionTimeout(self, ctimeout_secs):
        self.timeout_secs = ctimeout_secs
        AsyncDownloader.__connection_timeout = self.timeout_secs

    def setReadTimeout(self, rtimeout_secs):
        self.timeout_secs = rtimeout_secs
        AsyncDownloader.__read_timeout = self.timeout_secs

    def download(self):
        try:
            session = FuturesSession(max_workers=10)
            session.headers.update({'user-agent': AsyncDownloader.__user_agent})
            session.request(AsyncDownloader.__connection_timeout,
                            AsyncDownloader.__connection_timeout)
            results = []
            for url in AsyncDownloader.__urls:
                results.append(session.get(url))

            for result in results:
                response = result.result()
                filename = os.path.basename(response.url)
                if AsyncDownloader.__dest_path is None:
                    AsyncDownloader.__dest_path = pathlib.Path(filename)
                else:
                    AsyncDownloader.__dest_path = pathlib.Path(str(AsyncDownloader.__dest_path) + os.path.sep + filename).resolve()
                # save file in  directory
                print(AsyncDownloader.__dest_path) # Shows correct path
                with open(AsyncDownloader.__dest_path, 'wb') as fd:
                    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=128):
                        fd.write(chunk)

        except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
            print("Http Error:", errh)
        except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
            print("Error Connecting:", errc)
        except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
            print("Timeout Error:", errt)
        except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
            print("OOps: Something Else", err)
        else:
            return

    def printURLs(self):
        print(AsyncDownloader.__urls)
```

The print shows the correct path which is

```
C:\Users\XYZ\PycharmProjects\AsyncDownloaderTest\images\Spring-Landscape-HD-Wallpapers-25912.jpg
```

However `open` sees the wrong path

```
    with open(AsyncDownloader.__dest_path, 'wb') as fd:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\XYZ\\PycharmProjects\\AsyncDownloaderTest\\images\\Spring-Landscape-HD-Wallpapers-25912.jpg\\FUE7XiFApEqWZQ85wYcAfM.jpg'`
```

I think the identation is OK so I wonder what's wrong.

Comment: The path opened has `\FUE7XiFApEqWZQ85wYcAfM.jpg` added to the end.

Comment: You set `__dest_path` to a `filename` path first, then latter append the next filename to that. Why?

Comment: @MartijnPieters i want to set `__dest_path` to a filename ONLY if `__dest_path` is None ( aka null).Otherwise i do the else part.

Comment: I found my mistake .....at the next iteration of the loop...it will add a new filename to the full path of previous file as outline by Mike

Comment: **Exactly**. Why do you do that? `__dest_path` is `None` only the first time round. You then start appending names to the previous path.

Comment: Yes that was really bad design.I got rid of the if entirely.`with open(pathlib.Path(str(AsyncDownloader.__dest_path) + os.path.sep + filename).resolve(), 'wb') as fd:` looks much clearer

Comment: If you are using `pathlib.Path`, don't use string conversion and concatenation with `os.path.sep`, just use `AsyncDownloader.__dest_path / filename` to build a new path. See the [*Operators* section](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#operators).

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
AsyncDownloader.__dest_path = pathlib.Path(str(AsyncDownloader.__dest_path)          
                                           + os.path.sep + filename).resolve()
```

to:

```
AsyncDownloader.__dest_path = pathlib.Path(
   os.path.split(str(AsyncDownloader.__dest_path))[0] + os.path.sep + filename).resolve()
```

This adds the new file name to directory instead to the  full path name of the previous file.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following line

```
AsyncDownloader.__dest_path = pathlib.Path(str(AsyncDownloader.__dest_path)          
                                       + os.path.sep + filename).resolve()
```

to:

```
AsyncDownloader.__dest_path = pathlib.Path(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(AsyncDownloader.__dest_path), filename)).resolve()
```